# Is it possible to run Minecraft on an emulated PI?

Tags: video, qemu, minecraft

Is it possible to run Minecraft PI on an machine emulated using qemu?

When I try to launch Minecraft, I get this error:  "failed to open vchiq instance". There is no file named /dev/vchiq.  Some old posts on other sites suggest that it is not possible to run Minecraft because qemu does not emulate the Pi's graphics.  Is this still the case?

Comment: Get a real Pi. I have a Raspberry Pi and it runs without problems, and Herobrine.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi community on Stack Exchange - I've edited your post to include cross-referenced a couple of related questions - but whether they exactly help to answer your question is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message makes clear that Minecraft can't find the 
Pi GPU since it's not there. I'm pretty sure there is no way
around that requirement either.

If you are looking to use the Pi edition Python API, plugins
for Desktop Minecraft exist to emulate this API :
 http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/raspberryjuice/